# What does this mean when I try to parent armatures together?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

blender amateur here trying to rig a character. I have already created the skeleton for the character, but when I try to parent parts of the armature together so they can move as one, an error pops up. I've tried switching modes, creating new armatures, etc etc. and I'm not sure what to do! Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How are you parenting parts of the armature? Are you in bone edit mode? Are you  trying parent one bone to another?

Comment: I have tried in edit mode, doing what Nathan said, but this message inevitably pops up. I am trying to parent the bones of the arm and clavicle to the spine.

Comment: It looks as of you are using 2 different armatures. Try merging them with Ctrl J.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit parents in pose mode.  You need to be in edit mode.

Select your armature and change to edit mode.  Select the bone you wish parented, then shift select the bone you want to parent it to, and hit ctrl-p.  You can choose between connected and keep offset.

You can change the connected property via the properties window, bu you rarely need to.  If you make a bone connected, it will change the location of the head of that bone to the tail of its parent.

Comment: Hi, I've switched to edit mode and object mode and the same error message pops up.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to connect two different armatures?  You can parent them-- select future child, shift select future parent bone in pose mode, ctrl-p parent bone relative-- but you can't connect them.  You probably don't need them connected, but if you feel that you do, you can connect them by first joining the armatures: select one armature, shift select the other, ctrl-j in object mode.

Comment: I'm trying to parent them - if I move the skeleton, I want the arms and clavicle to move with/be affected by it in order to make an animation.

Comment: What you probably want to do is join the armatures, and then parent the clavicle appropriately, bioth as described above.